# Ignore file inside submodule

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-submodules

I want to be able to **ignore** a file or a folder inside `submodule` for example:

```
// the main project structure
- components_submodule
   - component-1.js
   - component-2.js
   - component-3.js
- config.js
- assets
- style
- .gitignore
- .gitmodule
```

I want the `submodule` repo to contain all components file above `component-1.js`, `component-2.js`, and `component-3.js`. But the main project repo to ignore for example `component-3.js`.

Comment: What does "ignore" mean here? The main project records which submodule commit was checked out, so you check out that commit there.

Comment: "ignore" means, I want `component-3.js` not to be included in the main project, or you can say (remove `component-3.js` from main project repo but keep it in `components_submodule`  submodule repo for other projects)

Comment: You mean you don't want it checked out, then. Use sparse checkout for that.

Comment: Could you please explain how to use it?